# Converting natural language to haiku?

Tags: nlp, translation

Is it possible to programmatically convert regular English into English haiku? Or is this something too complicated to contemplate? I have a feeling that this is a lot more involved than a [Pig Latin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_Latin) formatter.

Comment: <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504428/how-would-you-write-a-program-to-generate-haiku">This previously asked question</a> basically comes to the same conclusion Brandon does: it's not nearly as easy as you might think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd first need to find a way to count the number of syllables in a given word, take a look at the answers in [Detecting Syllables in a Word.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405161/detecting-syllables-in-a-word)

Keep in the mind the top voted answer references an entire thesis, so this is definitely more involved than a pig latin formatter.

Answer (score 7):

Must count syllables

Need nature references

Haiku's not easy

Answer (score 5):

Pig Latin is text substitution.  Haiku is poetry.

Find a regular expression to convert prose to poetry and you'll be rich.

Answer (score 5):

Pig Latin is easy.
Haiku is much different.
Syllables, not words.